# jquery skip list item

Tags: jquery, list

Is there a way for a jQuery function to "skip" an li? Such as Having 3 list items, you click on the 1st one, it calls a next() function, and skips the 2nd li and goes to the 3rd.

Current code is here:

$('ul.gallery li').click(function() {
    $(window).scrollTo($(this).next('li'), 800, {easing:'easeOutCirc', axis:'x', offset:-50 } );
});

I want it to skip the immediate li and go to the one after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to just call [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) again, like this:

```
$('ul.gallery li').click(function() {
    $(window).scrollTo($(this).next('li').next('li'), 
                       800, 
                       {easing:'easeOutCirc', axis:'x', offset:-50 });
});
```

If the `<li>` you wanted had a specific class, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff 2</li>
  <li class="selectMe">Stuff 3</li>
</ul>
```

You could use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) instead of [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), like this:

```
$('ul.gallery li').click(function() {
    $(window).scrollTo($(this).nextAll('li.selectMe:first'), 
                       800, 
                       {easing:'easeOutCirc', axis:'x', offset:-50 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add a class to the `LI` that you want to skip and use [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

and example from [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$("input:not(:checked) + span").css("background-color", "yellow");
```